# Calibri Font Issue with Arabic

Tags: fonts, arabic, arabic-support

Calibri font does not work with Arabic letters in MS Word. I have tried to install language packs, delete the font and reinstall, test the font in Adobe Photoshop but all with no luck.
The font work fine at my friend's laptop so it supports Arabic Language. I cannot find the cause and solution for this.
Any advise that could help me here would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the font "works fine" if it works on your friend's computer? Who says his or her computer isn't automatically applying font substitution, using a *completely different font*? Because Calibri [absolutely does not support Arabic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/calibri).

Answer (score 0):

Calibri on Windows11 has many subsets one of which is Arabic

Shown below is the Symbol dialog in MSWord

[image]

There is also the "Character Map" press the Windows-Key once then type "char" it will be listed, click advanced view.

[image]